# Infinispan size eviction + diskStore overflow

Tags: java, caching, infinispan

I am trying to configure Infinispan to set a maximum entries in memory, and additional entries (if there are more then the memory size) should be persisted to local file store. Is it possible to set in infinispan (I am doing a programmatic configuration) ? It was doable in ehcache I remember, but cannot google any manual on infinispan...

Answer (score 2):

The section describing the moving of entries from memory to the store when evicted is what is called as "passivation" in the Infinispan User guide here [1].

In regards to memory based eviction, I have to update the user guide but the original blog post with information on it can be found at [2].

[1] http://infinispan.org/docs/dev/user_guide/user_guide.html#eviction_anchor

[2] http://blog.infinispan.org/2015/09/memory-based-eviction.html

Comment: But the eviction is removal from the cache totally right? And I would like to make sure that if an an in memory cache size is exceeded, I don't loose the objects but they are stored in a filestore

Comment: Eviction, in Infinispan terminology, means moving out from in-memory (aka data container). If there's a cache store, it will be written there, if no persistence layer is defined, it will be really just dropped.

Comment: Actually I am not describing that correctly. Without passivation, entries are stored both into in-memory (for fast access) and into cache store. Then, eviction just drops the in-memory part. With passivation, the entry is written only to in-memory but when the entry is evicted, it is persisted in the cache store.

Comment: Also, without passivation, when an evicted entry is loaded from cache store, it stays there - so there are two copies. With passivation, "activation" happens on load - the entry is removed from the store and added to in-memory data-container.